# Write to .html file with exec master..xp_cmdshell

Tags: html, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

Below is my small code:

**Scenario 1**

```
declare @DataToWrite varchar(8000)

set @DataToWrite='<html><body><h1>This is a Heading</h1></body></html>'

DECLARE @CommandL1 varchar(8000)

SET @CommandL1 = 'echo'+@DataToWrite+'> D:\logs\Logs\HTMLFile.html'

print CommandL1 

exec master..xp_cmdshell @CommandL1
```

After executing it in the SSMS Query Window below are results:

Results Tab of SSMS:

```
**< was unexpected at this time.**
```

Messages Tab of SSMS:

```
echo<html><body><h1>This is a Heading</h1></body></html>> 
D:\logs\Logs\HTMLFile.html

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Why it is not allowing me to write this HTML CODE TO .html file ?

**Scenario 2**

Below code runs fine and generates the HTML file in the desired location:

```
declare @DataToWrite varchar(8000)
set @DataToWrite='t'
DECLARE @CommandL1 varchar(8000)

SET @CommandL1 = 'echo '+@DataToWrite+'> D:\logs\Logs\HTMLFile.html'

print @CommandL1 

exec master..xp_cmdshell @CommandL1
```

Note:

Please don't get confused with "This Is a Heading" thing. Stackoverflow editor is converting it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two issues:

You have missed space between `echo` and the string variable `@DataToWrite`.

You can't refer to a variable without `@`

```
print CommandL1
```

it should be

```
print @CommandL1
```

You also need to escape (using ^) special characters (tags) in your string to print them in the command line or write those into a file.

try the following:

```
declare @DataToWrite varchar(8000)
set @DataToWrite='<html><body><h1>This is a Heading</h1></body></html>'
DECLARE @CommandL1 varchar(8000)
SET @CommandL1 = 'echo '+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DataToWrite, '<', '^<'), '>', '^>')+' > D:\logs\Logs\HTMLFile.html'
print @CommandL1 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @CommandL1
```